# Keras convolutional net classification adding 1D extra feature possible?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, keras, conv-neural-network

I have built a successful convolutional net using Keras classifying certain brain activity from the EEG. I would however like to improve it by adding an extra feature of which we know it is predictive of this brain activity; age, which is of course a 1D array of a different scale. How do I go about this?

Can I add age to the 'image' as the extra dimension? Or should I use age to classify brain activity in a different model and then merge the two models? Or are there options?

```
> X.shape  
 (745,13,60,1) (Trials, channels, frequencies, extra_dim)

> age.shape
(745,)
```

Thanks for any tip and thinking with me!

Best,

Hanneke

Comment: isn't age is just another input?

Comment: I'm just not sure how to 'put it in' into a Keras API convolutional network such as this:
def conv5(self,units = 512):
    inp =  Input(shape = self.shape[1:], name='inp')
    
    x = Conv2D(units, kernel_size=(1,1), strides = (1,1), activation='relu', data_format='channels_last', name='conv1')(inp)    
   etc. etc. etc.

Comment: Is each EEG data a timeline or a single picture?

Comment: Thanks for thinking with me! I have 745 trials, and each trial consists of a 13 channels (lines) with 60 frequency points, the values in the matrix represent the powerspectrum.

Comment: So, it's a timeline with 60 steps and 13 channels?

Comment: is age the same for every brain? So your vector has the same element in very entry

Answer (score 0):

Not related: Why the extra dim? Are you using Conv2D? You should probably get better results with Conv1D, with `(exams, timeSteps, channels)`.

Also: did you make sure you're using `data_format='channels_first'`? Keras' default is `data_format='channels_last'`.

---

**Answer for Conv2D:**

You must choose a form of interacting the two sets of data. This interaction can be very creative and there is no rule. Two possibilities:

- Multiply this 1D value somewhere, or add, or think of nice operations (requires functional API model with two inputs).
- Add the age as an additional channel to every step (I like this one)

Adding the age as an additional channel:

```
x_with_age = np.empty((745,14,60,1)) 
age = age.reshape((745,1,1,1))

x_with_age[:,:13] = X
x_with_age[:,-1:] = age
```

Train the model using `x_with_age` as input.

---

**If following the Conv1D suggestion:**

```
#this is using channels_last, which is keras' default   
#if your data is channels_first, then just invert the shapes below

X = should be something like (745, 60, 13)

x_with_age = np.empty((745,60,14)) 
age = age.reshape((745,1,1))

x_with_age[:,:,:13] = X
x_with_age[:,:,-1:] = age
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!  I was thinking of the matrix as 745 pictures of 13 (EEG channels not RGB channels (sorry for the confusion)) by 60 (freq point) pixels! I now have a 3d matrix with np.expand_dims(X, axis = -1) and 'channels_last'. By the way the validation accuracy is on average 85-93%. (Categorical cross entropy) validation loss about .25%. I chose categorical because I want to know how sure the model is. So would I still need to use channels_first? And does the extra channel with age still work then? I thought it would make more sense on the 3rd axis in the way I built my matrix?

Comment: Channels first or last is an option that doesn't change results. It's about your preference and about how your data is organized. If you change this option, make sure to permute or swap the axes of your data as well. I asked because I was confused about your 4D data.

Comment: So... you had transofmed you "EEG channels" in "keras pixels" and kept just "one keras channel". Is that it?

Comment: Yes I did. Now I added an extra channel with the age on the 3rd axis. Thanks very much Daniel, It seems to work very well and boost the accuracy! The model is still overfitting a bit but I will start tweaking the hyperparameters and regularization/dropout now. Have a nice afternoon!